# ForEach value is only the first item in the Array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have been trying to use SwiftUI to make some UI for my app, and I need A String to be separated into chars and have each char have its own component, so far I have this:

```
HStack{
    ForEach(Array("val")) { char in 
        //Stuff here
    }
}
```

I have an extension for Character which gives it an id so it works in this case, but the problem is if I pass in "val" all of the components have the text "v" not "v" "a" "l" in separate components, this also occurs if I pass in an array of chars, something like ["a", "b"] would become "a" and "a". I am sorry if this is a bad question I am just very new to SwiftUI and Swift in general.

Comment: Don't make an extension of `Character` conforming to `Identifiable`. Instead, use `ForEach(Array("val"), id: \.self)`.

Comment: That actually did it!

Comment: @George_E, why not make `Character` conform to `Identifiable`?

Comment: @NewDev I edited my answer and added reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make an extension of `Character` conforming to `Identifiable`. Instead, do the following:

```
ForEach(Array("val"), id: \.self)
```

I don't know your implementation of the extension, and so just using `\.self` with `Character` works. However, you can conform `Character` to `Identifiable`, such as:

```
extension Character: Identifiable {
    
    public var id: Character { self }
}
```

which is equivalent to `\.self`. From the issue experienced I can assume there is a problem with the implementation, such as giving the same `id`, for example:

```
extension Character: Identifiable {
    
    public var id: Int { 1 }
}
```